# trying to make paint with python turtle module

Tags: python, paint, python-turtle

I'm a beginner and i'm trying to make paint with python turtle but my code gives an error. I've tried everything I could think of but it still isn't working.

```
from turtle import *
from menuitem import MenuItem

def changePenColor(c):
    """Changes the system turtle's color to c."""
    color(c)

def createMenu(callBack):
    """Displays 6 menu items to respond to the given callback function."""
    x = - (window_width() / 2) + 30
    y = 100
    colors = ('red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black', 'purple')
    shape = "circle"
    for color in colors:
        MenuItem(x, y, shape, color, callBack)
        y -= 30
def main():
    """Creates a menu for selecting colors."""
    reset()
    shape("turtle")
    createMenu(color)
    return "done!"

if __name__=='__main__':
    msg = main()
    print(msg)
    mainloop()
```

And this code in a different file:

```
from turtle import Turtle

class MenuItem(Turtle):
    """Represents a menu item."""
def __init__(self, x, y, shape, color, callBack):
    """Sets the initial state of a menu item."""
    Turtle.__init__(x, y, self, shape = shape, visible = False)
    self.speed(0)
    self.up()
    self.goto(x, y)
    self.color(color, color)
    self._callBack=callBack
    self.onclick(lambda x,y: self._callBack(color))
    self.showturtle()
```

If anyone knows what I can do to fix this, I'd be happy to know.
Thanks

Comment: You say it isn't working but not how it isn't working. What should it do? What is your expected input and output? Can you provide the full error message? Essentially we need a complete [mre]. Please read [ask] and see if you can improve the question to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please [edit] that into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is somewhat confused.  Specifically:

```
from turtle import *
```

Just don't.  Particularly in a module.  Import as little as you need to get the job done.

```
createMenu(color)
```

This should be `createMenu(changePenColor)` and `changePenColor()` should be defined in the *main* module, not the MenuItem class module.

```
Turtle.__init__(x, y, self, shape = shape, visible = False)
```

first three arguments to `__init__` shouldn't be there and you should use `super`, all as @Evan notes.

```
reset()
self._callBack=callBack
```

These two statments are effectively no-ops and can be left out.

Below is my rework of your code that I believe does what you're attempting to do.  For example purposes, instead of the main module, I just used a `if __name__ == '__main__':` for testing:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

COLORS = ('red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black', 'purple')

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

class MenuItem(Turtle):
    ''' Represents a menu item. '''

    def __init__(self, x, y, shape, color, callBack):
        ''' Sets the initial state of a menu item '''

        super().__init__(shape=shape, visible=False)
        self.penup()
        self.goto(x, y)
        self.color(color)

        self.onclick(lambda x, y: callBack(color))

        self.showturtle()

def createMenu(callBack):
    ''' Displays 6 menu items to respond to the given callback function. '''

    screen = Screen()

    x = CURSOR_SIZE * 1.5 - screen.window_width() / 2
    y = 100

    for color in COLORS:
        MenuItem(x, y, 'circle', color, callBack)
        y -= CURSOR_SIZE * 1.5

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from turtle import getscreen, getturtle

    def changePenColor(c):
        ''' Changes the turtle's color to c. '''

        turtle.color(c)

    screen = getscreen()  # singular screen instance

    turtle = getturtle()  # default turtle
    turtle.shape('turtle')

    # Create a menu for selecting colors.
    createMenu(changePenColor)

    screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: do you also happen to know how to add an option to it so that it lets you change the width of the line the turtle draws? thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your first line of the `__init__` function on your `MenuItem` class, use this

```
super().__init__(shape=shape, visible=False)
```

instead of

```
Turtle.__init__(x, y, self, shape = shape, visible = False)
```

You don't need to pass in `x`, `y`, or `self`, because you are already setting the position by saying `self.goto(x, y)`. Also, use `super()` instead of `Turtle`, because you need to initialize the superclass, not just another instance of `Turtle`. By saying `Turtle.__init__(...)` you are creating an instance of that object and doing nothing with it. By saying `super().__init__(...)`, you are initializing the superclass of your object, which is what you always need to do when you are subclassing an object (in this case `Turtle`).

Note: your `__init__` function needs to be indented, but I'll assume that was a pasting error.

Comment: Can you explain why they should use your code? What have you changed and why? I think this could be an excellent answer with a bit more explanation